# homework question, comment pointing to myhomeworkdone.com

Tags: discussion, comments, spam

The question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39680066/773113

User "dit" added the following comment:

```
check this: myhomeworkdone.com – dit 24 mins ago
```

I think it can be argued that it is unethical to point someone to such a site, ***and*** the site is a commercial site, so the comment can be thought of as spam.

What do we do about things like this?

Comment: Close the question, vote to delete it, call it a day.

Comment: @Tunaki the question is of course worth closing, but what I am mainly concerned about is not the question, it is the comment.

Comment: Prefer 'not constructive' though, it isn't strictly rude..

Comment: Double standard, if that is unethical then why wouldn't it be unethical for the questioner to ask somebody to do his homework?   It *always* having to be the contributors to the site that are expected to keep up the standards but expecting nothing from those that ask for help is exhausting and unfair and creates a web site with a lot of crap questions.

Comment: I wasn't expecting a business like that to exist, but I can't say I'm surprised...

Comment: @HansPassant: "*It always having to be the contributors to the site that are expected to keep up the standards*" People who ask questions *are* "contributors to the site."

Comment: A user that asks somebody else to do his homework is **not** a contributor.  Jeez-marie, do I really have to spell that out to make it obvious?

Comment: @BoltClock it's a goldmine

Answer (score 8):

> I think it can be argued that it is unethical to point someone to such a site, and the site is a commercial site, so the comment can be thought of as spam.

Hardly. We all know the link wasn't posted with the intent of spamming, so treating it as such is disingenuous. It was posted to make a point, much like LMGTFY links.

If anything, it’s a bit rude—you can flag it as rude or not constructive if you feel like it.